# How to use environement variable in client side Astro?

Tags: environment-variables, vite, astrojs

I would like to use an api key stored in an environment variable. I know I can just put it directly in the html (I don't think it is bad security wise since it is a public key). But I can't get access it an my react component.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
      SetRecaptchaKey(import.meta.env.VITE_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY);
      console.log(recaptchaKey)
    });
```

outside my component function (above) I have this:

```js
const key = import.meta.env;
console.log(key)
```

it logs the object in the console, and it has the variable i'm looking for.

Another thing, is that I have two VITE_... variables and another variable. Only one of VITE_.. is loaded (which is what I want) but I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the behavior or documentation was changed after the last answer, but you need to prefix it with `PUBLIC_`.

So if you have an environment variable named `TEST_VAR`, you need to rename it to `PUBLIC_TEST_VAR` and then it should be accessible in client side components as `PUBLIC_TEST_VAR`.

For example as `import.meta.env.PUBLIC_TEST_VAR` in a Astro React component.

**Please note that this variable will be leaked in the client side code!**

Answer (score 0):

In order to use an environment variable in client side Astro, you need to prefix the variable with "ASTRO_". For example, if you have an environment variable named "TEST_VAR", you would access it in client side Astro as "ASTRO_TEST_VAR".

Comment: It works. But how can I use it inside the component? It returns undefined. But It logs if it is outside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix with `PUBLIC_`.

> [...] all environment variables are available in server-side code, only environment variables prefixed with `PUBLIC_` are available in client-side code for security purposes.

So if you have an environment variable named `VITE_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY`, you need to create a new var named `PUBLIC_VITE_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY`.

```
VITE_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY="..."  # server-side
PUBLIC_VITE_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY="${VITE_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY}"  # client-side
```